# Tag merge passenger and phusion-passenger

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I think that [passenger](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/passenger) and [phusion-passenger](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/phusion-passenger) need to be merged - they refer to the same technology.

[passenger](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/passenger) is listed on 50 questions and [phusion-passenger](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/phusion-passenger) is on 181.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)